# Grouped static table background issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

[image: Screen]

Is there a way how to remove those two "darker" -ish places above and beneath active table? I have already tinkered with Opaque options without any success.

Note: The screenshot is taken while "dragging down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michal, I'm having trouble understanding how this is happening. I tried a similar setup on one of my view controllers in a storyboard. On the left you can see the result and on the right you can see how it's set up in the storyboard. As you can see, this is a standard UITableView with static cells without the "dark background" issue. This also doesn't appear while dragging down.

[image]

This could be caused by something that's wrong with your setup. Could you elaborate so I can help you?

Comment: I had alpha set to 0.9 and I have no idea why...probably not knowingly clicked on it. Thanks for advice!:)